# Dart Main File (and other essential files) Not Created In New Project

Tags: flutter, dart, intellij-idea, program-entry-point

I am learning dart/flutter using InetlliJ, and when I go to create a new dart project, it only creates a few useless files. No main.dart. I have all the most recent versions of flutter and dart installed.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TeoS.png)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, when creating a new project you cannot name it with a upper case letter for the first letter, the first letter must be lowercase, or the IDE does not recognize it as a new project and does not create the main folders

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. If you go File->Project Structure->Modules->click the (+) sign and select a new module, then all the proper files will be made. Apparently when it comes to Dart programming language, intelliJ requires you to create a subsequent module inside the project folder.
I also figured out that the new module you create has to have a completely lowercase title, otherwise the project problem repeats itself but in the new module folder this time.

Answer (score 0):

How did you generate your new project?

You can [install](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/test-drive?tab=androidstudio#create-app) the Flutter plugin on your editor, and you can create a Flutter Project using this [guide](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue that the IDE would make the project, but there would be no bin or a main file(i.e : Dart Main File (and other essential files) Not Created In New Project). I resolved this issue by simply changing the (NM)naming convention of the project. Example In my case 1st(NM) = "DartProject", then I changed the naming to 2nd(NM) = "dart-project".